# Client server using WebSphere MQ

Tags: c++, multithreading, client-server, message-queue, ibm-mq

I am choosing between two options for a client server application -

First - Go for a TCP/IP (Pure socket based) approach with multithreaded server and manage the synchronization of send and receive myself.

Second - use and WebSphere MQ approach (MQI). Basically one input Queue and one output Queue for the server. The clients write to the server input queue and the server puts the reply in output queue with some correlation identifier etc. So only 2 queues needed.The server program is multithreaded (thread pools) and multiple threads will read on the input queue and write on the output queue.

Question - I am leaning towards the second approach but have few doubts  -

1. Are MQI calls thread safe? Do I have to use some mutual exclusion for `MQGET` and `MQPUT` for the queues.
2. Will the performance of MQ based approach be lower than socket based. By performance I mean two things.

   a. Are IBM MQ queue operation slower than direct socket connections in general?

   b. Will the mutual exclusion locks on `MQGET` and `MQPUT` slow down the message processing?

   c. I plan to have a load of around 10000 messages per second (each around 100 bytes). The replies  will be about 5 KB (XML messages). Is this a practical load for IBM MQ based approach?

Note - The language is C++ and operating system for the server is Solaris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use case you are describing is incredibly narrow.  It's never just a case of "sockets or queues" but other considerations must factor into the business case:

1. How will the thing be monitored and managed?  Will it be necessary to write all the parts that report system health to the NOC and provide message stats, or can I use what MQ provides?
2. Do I need queuing or is this truly a synchronous app?
3. Is this really point-to-point or do the apps involved participate in an ecosystem of services and upstream/downstream connections?  What else does it need to integrate with?
4. Is there a need for message enrichment, routing, fan-in, fan-out, pub/sub or other functionality?  Write code or use WMQ/WMQ Broker native features?
5. Do the connections require authentication?  Encryption?    Write code or use WMQ native features?
6. Are there regulatory compliance factors involved and if so what's the cost of auditing custom code vs. COTS transport?
7. Does the shop have deep C++ skills and prepared to maintain that depth of bench for the lifetime of the code?
8. How is the connection configuration managed and does it support HA and DR seamlessly?  Write code or use WMQ native features?
9. How will exception logic and automatic reconnect be managed?  Write code or use WMQ native features?

The business case has to consider a lot more than raw speed.  This is especially true when both alternatives are capable of meeting the throughput requirement as should be the case here.  Once the functional requirements are met it is all these other aspects (and more I haven't thought of off the top of my head) that must be considered in the business case.

As for the specific questions...

Access to the queues is managed the way you'd hope.  Multiple threads compete for the same messages but a message delivered to one is not delivered to another thread.  Exceptions are if the message is rolled back and becomes available again or the app is using pub/sub and intentionally receiving more than one copy of the message.

On the app side, the calls are thread safe within a session.  So all threads using the same session `COMMIT` together.  Usually a pair of threads using request/reply operates cooperatively.  Otherwise, one session per thread gives you what you need.

As for performance, this is an apples-to-oranges comparison.  The question is whether a C++ sockets program that provides all the services, diagnostics, resiliency and other features of an async messaging transport performs on par with that transport.  The answer there is usually no.  WMQ has been optimized for 20 years to do one thing and to do it extremely well.  A new custom C++ sockets program will move data faster but not provide the same functionality.  So it comes down to whether the app needs so little of WMQ's functionality that it's cheaper in the long run to custom code the few functions it needs, then maintain that for the life of the app.  Again, the answer is usually no.

For specifics on message throughput rates, go to the [SupportPacs](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs) page and look for the ones with names beginning MP__ for theplatform and version you need.  Achieving 10k MPS for small messages is possible on even modest hardware.